# Unable to save the complete web fetched values into csv document

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
def fin_car(url):
    x = {}                                                                                                        
    y = []
    page = ''
    while page == '':
        try:
            page = requests.get(url)
        except:
            print("Connection refused by the server..")
            print("Let me sleep for 5 seconds")
            print("ZZzzzz...")
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Was a nice sleep, now let me continue...")
            continue
    #page = requests.get(url)                                                                                      
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')                                                                    
    Precio = []                                                                                                   
    price = soup.find('div' , 'price').text                                                                                                                                            
    Precio = (str(price).strip())
    print (Precio)     
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #                           #Tipo Propiedad          #Tipo de oferta                                          #
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    Tipo_Propiedad = []                                                                                           
    Tipo_de_oferta = []                                                                                           
    T_1 = soup.find('div' , 'box').h1.text
    text =  (str(T_1).strip())
    l = text.find(' ')
    m = text.find(' ', l+1)
    n = text.find(' ', m+1)
    Tipo_Propiedad = text[0 : l]
    Tipo_de_oferta = text[m+1 : n]
    print (Tipo_Propiedad)
    print (Tipo_de_oferta)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #                           #Departamento  #Ciudad #Zona #Barrio                                              #
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    Departamento = []                                                                                             
    Ciudad = []                                                                                                   
    Zona = []                                                                                                     
    Barrio = []                                                                                                   
    first = soup.find('div' , 'breadcrumb left')                                                                  
    link = first.find('div')                                                                                      
    a_link = link.findAll('a')                                                                                    
    box1 = []                                                                                                     
    for row in a_link:                                                                                            
        box1.append(row.text)                                                                                     
    Departamento = (box1[1:2].pop())                                                                          
    Ciudad = (box1[2:3].pop())                                                                                
    Zona = (box1[3:4].pop())                                                                                  
    Barrio = (box1[4:5])                                                                                
    print (Departamento)                                                                                     
    print (Ciudad)                                                                                           
    print (Zona)                                                                                             
    print (Barrio)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #              #Área     #Habitaciones  #Baños #Parqueaderos                                                  #
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    box_2 = soup.find('div' ,'features clearfix')                                                                 
    box_2_1  = box_2.findAll('span')                                                                              
    box2 = []                                                                                                     
    Área=[]                                                                                                       
    Habitaciones = []                                                                                             
    Baños = []                                                                                                    
    Parqueaderos = []                                                                                             
    for row2 in box_2_1:
        box2.append(str(row2.text).strip())
    for i in box_2_1:
        a = box2[0:1].pop()
        b = box2[1:2].pop()
        c = box2[2:3].pop()
        d = box2[3:4].pop()
        a1 = a[0 : a.find(' ')]
    Área = (a1)                                                                              
    Habitaciones = (b.rstrip()[-1])                                                                      
    Baños = (c.rstrip()[-1])                                                                             
    Parqueaderos =(d) 
    print (Área)                                                                                            
    print (Habitaciones)                                                                                    
    print (Baños)                                                                                           
    print (Parqueaderos)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #            #Área_Privada #Área_Const #Antigüedad #Admón #Estrato #Estado #Piso_No                           #
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
     box_3 = soup.find('div' ,'row features_2 ')                                                                   
    box_3_1  = box_3.findAll('li')                                                                                                                                                                                   #
    Área_Privada = []                                                                                             
    Área_Const = []                                                                                               
    Antigüedad = []                                                                                               
    Admón = []                                                                                                    
    Estrato = []                                                                                                  
    Estado = []                                                                                                   
    Piso_No = []                                                                                                  
    for li in box_3_1:                                                                                            
        heading_words = li.b.text.split()                                                                                                                                                             #
        target_content = str(li.br.next_sibling).strip()                                                                                                                                             #
        if "privada:" in heading_words:                                                                           
            Área_Privada = (target_content)                                                                                                                                            #
        elif "Const.:" in heading_words:                                                                          
            Área_Const = (target_content)                                                                     
        elif "Antigüedad:" in heading_words:                                                                      
            Antigüedad = (target_content)                                                                     
        elif "Admón:" in heading_words:                                                                         
            Admón = (target_content)
        elif "Estrato:" in heading_words:                                                                         
            Estrato = (target_content)                                                                                                                                               
        elif "Estado:" in heading_words:                                                                          
            Estado = (target_content)                                                                         
        elif "Piso" in heading_words:                                                                             
            Piso_No = (target_content)                                                                           
    print (Área_Privada)                                                                                                                                                                                #
    print (Área_Const)                                                                                       
    print (Antigüedad)                                                                                       
    print (Admón)                                                                                            
    print (Estrato)                                                                                                                                                                                      #
    print (Estado)                                                                                           
    print (Piso_No[0:1])
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #               #Actualizado             #Visitas               #Código_FincaRaiz                             #                                                                                        #
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    box4 = soup.find('div' , 'box_content row')                                                                   
    box4_1 = box4.findAll('span')                                                                                 
    vis = []                                                                                                      
    Actualizado = []                                                                                                         
    Visitas = []                                                                                                         
    Código_FincaRaiz = []                                                                                         
    for i in box4_1:                                                                                              
        vis.append((str(i.text).strip()))   
    for j in box4_1:
        e = vis[0:1].pop()
        f = vis[2:3].pop()
    Actualizado = e
    Código_FincaRaiz = f                                                                                   
    url="https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/WebServices/Statistics.asmx/GetAdvertVisits?idAdvert={}&idASource=40&idType=1001".format(Código_FincaRaiz)                                                                        #
    page1 = requests.get(url)                                                                                     
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.content , 'lxml')                                                                 
    visit1 = soup1.find('double').text                                                                            
    Visitas = (visit1)                                                                                                                                                                          
    print (Actualizado)                                                                                      
    print (Visitas)                                                                                          
    print (Código_FincaRaiz)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    x['Código FincaRaiz'] = Código_FincaRaiz
    x['Departamento'] = Departamento
    x['Ciudad'] = Ciudad
    x['Zona'] = Zona
    x['Barrio'] = Barrio
    x['Tipo Propiedad'] = Tipo_Propiedad
    x['Tipo de oferta'] = Tipo_de_oferta
    x['Precio'] = Precio
    x['Área'] = Área
    x['Área Privada'] = Área_Privada
    x['Área Const.'] = Área_Const
    x['Antigüedad'] = Antigüedad
    x['Baños'] = Baños
    x['Habitaciones'] = Habitaciones
    x['Parqueaderos'] = Parqueaderos
    x['Admón'] = Admón
    x['Estrato'] = Estrato
    x['Estado'] = Estado
    x['Piso No.'] = Piso_No
    x['Actualizado'] = Actualizado
    x['Visitas'] = Visitas
    y.append(x)
x = {}                                                                                                        
y = []
filename = 'Fincar.csv'
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['Código FincaRaiz','Departamento','Ciudad','Zona','Barrio', 'Tipo Propiedad', 'Tipo de oferta',
                                  'Precio' , 'Área' , 'Área Privada' , 'Área Const.', 'Antigüedad', 'Baños' , 'Habitaciones',
                                  'Parqueaderos' , 'Admón', 'Estrato' , 'Estado' , 'Piso No.' , 'Actualizado', 'Visitas'])
    w.writeheader()
    for x in y:
        w.writerow(x)a
tab = []
xen = []
key_value = 'https://www.fincaraiz.com.co'
for i in range(2,6):
    tab.append('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/?ad=30|{}||||1||||||||||||||||||||||1|||1||||||'.format(i))
for j in tab:
    page = requests.get(j)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'lxml')
    index = soup.findAll('div' , 'span-title')
    for i in index:
        xen.append(i.find('a').get('href'))
    for j in xen:
        url = (key_value + j)
        fin_car(url)
```

I've tried to fetch values from list of pages and trying to save the file to csv document, however csv document only storing the last value inside the csv document.

Tried multiple ways but it always giving the same output.

also the column with the blank values need to be filled with nil value, however it posting only [] symbol.

New to python and find it difficult to saving it to python. Need your support to achieve this task.

How should I proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fin_car(url):
    x = {}                                                                                                        
    y = []
...
x = {}                                                                                                        
y = []
```

These values are in different scopes. Assigning `x` inside `fin_car` doesn't affect it outside. You could change that using a `global` statement, but much better is to return from the function.

Even if you were changing the outside values of `x` and `y`, you only call `fin_car` long after writing to the CSV. The order of events in your code matters.

I suggest:

```
def fin_car(url):
    x = {}
    ...
    return x

with open...:
    w = csv.DictWriter(...)
    ...
    for j in tab:
        ...
        for j in xen:
            url = ...
            w.writerow(fin_car(url))
```

You don't need `y` at all.

Comment: Also is there any option that I can save the output directly to sql

Comment: @sudharsonns yes, there are plenty of options, googe "python sql". If you get stuck on a specific issue, ask a new question about it.

Comment: what is meant by 'create a bot to build database' ?

Comment: Trying with sqlite3 to save my lists into database

Comment: @sudharsonns a bot is just a program. I'd need the context to explain more. But I don't think that phrase is important to understand how to solve your problem.

Comment: The exact phrase is "create a bot to build database of real estate information. Scrapper can enter in each properties of the list and retrieve the data visible", so I understand need to create a program to fetch data from website and store in sqldatabase

Comment: @sudharsonns Try going through http://pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-sqlite-in-python/ or http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/